# Tiled Plot using plot.kmeans function

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, k-means

I am trying to create a tiled plot using plot.kmeans functions from the package "useful". This can be done very easily for base plot function using par() or layout(), or in ggplot using facests. I want to visualize results of various runs of kmeans with different number of clusters using plot or plot.kmeans function from the package "useful". I have tried par() and layout(), but I only get one plot not multiple plots.
Consider the following code segment:

```
results1 <- kmeans(x=dataset1,centers=5,nstart = 25)
results2 <- kmeans(x=dataset2,centers=5,nstart = 25)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot.kmeans(results1,dataset1)
plot.kmeans(results2,dataset2)
```

I have two datasets and apply kmeans on them separately. I want to draw results of both datasets side by side. plot.kmeans is good function to see results of clustering. But somehow i feel that we cannot two or more plots side by side like we do in case of base plotting facility. If instead of plot.kmeans, I use base plot functions it will work. So thats my problem in brief. 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have added code in question, please have a look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `plot.kmeans` from the package "useful" (not to be confused with general qualifier 'a useful package) returns a ggplot2 object. These do *not* work with `par()` or `layout()`.

Look instead at `grid.arrange` from the "gridExtra" package:

```
results1 <- kmeans(x=dataset1,centers=5,nstart = 25)
results2 <- kmeans(x=dataset2,centers=5,nstart = 25)
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- plot.kmeans(results1,dataset1)
p2 <- plot.kmeans(results2,dataset2)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```